# class 'numpy.int32' wanted, but type() function only shows: numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, output

I want to send a numpy array as a digital output through a NI card. I am using the nidaqmx package from NI (national instruments).
For the digital output they expect a  array. I converted my numpy arrays to int32, but it still does not work and when I checked the array with the type() function it gave numpy.ndarray as class.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array(np.zeros(100), dtype = np.int32)
q = np.array(np.ones(50), dtype = np.int32)

vec = np.concatenate((p,q))

type(vec)
```

Out:

```
numpy.ndarray
```

expected:

```
numpy.int32
```

Comment: You want `vec.dtype`. `type(vec)` is checking the type of the array as a whole

Comment: if you want to know the datatype used _in_ the array, try `vec.dtype`

Comment: The type of `vec` is just a `numpy.array`,  `numpy.int32` is the type of the element of `vec`, you can try `type(vec[0])` for example.

Comment: okay, but then I get: `vec.dtype` = `dtype('int32')`, but what i need is `numpy.int32`

Comment: @DieKrone94 maybe edit your question to include the relevant part of the code you've written and the error you're getting back.  what you're currently saying is unclear

Comment: There is no error here.

Comment: You can pass dtype to np.zeros and np.ones. This way you can avoid pointless copying during creation of p and q arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `vec.dtype` to see the type of what the array contains. `type(vec)` tells you the type of `vec`, which is obviously a `numpy.array`. The output of `vec.dtype` is `dtype('int32')`. It is the same as `np.int32`, check for yourself:

```
vec.dtype == np.int32
```

Output:

```
True
```

The code is fine..

Comment: Thank you, you are right the code was right, the gadget I wanted to control simply wanted a different kind of input. But thank you anyways I understand know what the difference is between asking the type of the vector and one element of the vector.